# Only selecting values if other column has a certain value in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a structure like this:

```
user_id     platform
aaa         ios
bbb         ios
ccc         android
ccc         ios
ddd         ios
ddd         android
```

I am trying to get `user_id`'s that are present in both `ios` and `android` platforms.

I tried:

```
SELECT user_id  FROM `table`
where platform in ('ios') and platform in ('android')
group by user_id
LIMIT 100
```

But I get 0 results. The idea is to check cross-platform users and if `user_id` is shared between devices. The data is new to me, I am trying to understand it and I am not sure if my approach is correct since it returns nothing.

Desired result:

```
user_id    
ccc
ddd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `IN` and add a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT user_id 
FROM `table`
WHERE platform in ('ios', 'android')
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT platform) = 2
LIMIT 100;
```

If the table has no `user_id`/`platform` duplicates, then just use `COUNT(*)`.